# App URLs in web-pages don't take me to the app in app-store on iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore

On my iPad2 (iOS6), when a web-page has a link to their app in the app-store, following the link does not open that app in the app-store. Instead, the app-store opens but does not jump to that app... I have to try searching for it.

It seems to happen every time - is this a known issue?

Comment: Can you provide a sample url? I'll try it for you.

Comment: The link might be faulty. Try it on another device.

Comment: I used to have a similar problem that was due to app store regionalization. I was logged into iCloud with an Apple ID that was tied to the US, but I was logged into iTunes with an Apple ID that was tied to Spain. Browser links to the app store would never resolve properly.

Comment: Try force-quitting the App Store on your iPad. Go to your Home Screen. Then double-click the home button to open your multitasking bar. Locate the App Store in this bar. Press and hold the App Store icon until the icons begin to wiggle. Then tap the Red X next to the App Store icon to remove it from the multitasking bar. Now, try clicking on the URL again to see if it loads the app you are looking for.